# Dynamic Content. Change component based on Link clicked

Tags: html, angularjs

I use AngularJS 4,

And I have Components, every of them has a relationship to the `menubar`.

The `menubar` and `home` is pre-loaded in `root` component.

What I'm going to do is to make `menubar` navigation link changes the content in home (Particularly said that `home` component will changed to another component).

Now, the problem is, the link didn't work, it doesn't change anything. The `home` can't be changed.

---

app.component.html

```
<main>
    <app-menubar></app-menubar>
    <app-home ng-include="template"></app-home>
</main>
```

menubar.component.html

```
<ul>
    <a href="#" ng-click="template='src/app/home/home.component.html'"><li><img src="src/news.svg" alt="news"><span>Home</span></li></a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="template='src/app/contact/contact.component.html'"><li><img src="src/contact.svg" alt="contact"><span>Contact</span></li></a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="template='src/app/about/about.component.html'"><li><img src="src/about us.svg" alt="about us"><span>About</span></li></a>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into the Angular-Tutorial? [this one](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) is for Angular 2, but it should still cover everything you're trying to do.

For this, you would use a router-module (which you will almost always use in Angular, it's pretty cool)
The steps are as following:

- set up the router-module
- insert your links (for each page, a relative link with the component for it)
- replace your links in menubar.component.html with:

`<a routerLink="/welcome-page">Welcome</a>`

- don't Forget to also include a tag as following: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

this tag will contain all the page-source and is where Angular maps the router-links to

Once you get it, it's really easy and convenient

Comment: I've looked up for Angular Tutorials but that is the most logical way to do such. I'll try what you've given to me.

Comment: Thanks, so that's what they call the Dynamical Content, "Routing". I'll search for that Keyword.

Comment: Yes, for normal web-development, yours would be a perfect approach :) But since Angular runs all "pages" as a single-page-application, it Needs a Little different way to organize linking and such, because with normal links, the browser normally reloads the page, which is not what you want if you Programm a single-page-application.

It's not that far from conventional linking, you just Need to set up a router, which is no big deal with the tutorials and offers a great way afterwards of Managing the application (in Addition to already enable angular-routing). Good luck trying :)

Comment: Glad it helped :)